# extract headers from dataframe's column containing both headers and values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to read an excel file that has a column that consists of both numerical information and headers. Below I enclose the screenshot of this excel file:
[image: excel file]

As you can see, in the column "Specification" I have rows with numbers and rows with string "Model ...". I need to load this file and access information about every model, for example extract information about the number of sold Model 1 blue fountain pens in set of 2 (cell G13 on the screenshot).

What I tried was to load the table through `pd.read_excel(path)`, but I have no idea how to group this data into data about particular models.

I also tried this:

```
data = pd.read_excel(path, header=[5,6])
data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=data['Specification'])
```

Unfortunately obtained df consisted only on NaNs.

Comment: Could you show the output of `pd.read_excel(path, header=[5,6], index_col=[0], sheet_name='Brand1')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from reading the excel file, the main issue you’ll have here is that the specification column has repeated values, so if you set it as an index and try getting `2`, it’s not going to know which model to return.

To load the data:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, header=[5,6], sheet_name='Brand1', na_values='-')
```

- `sheet_name` allows to specify the sheet, and thus make sure you get the right one
- `na_values` is interesting as it allows to remove all the values marked `-` in your sheet.

Now let’s try and build a better index. We’ll use the 2 first columns:

```
>>> idx_cols = df[['Specification', 'Code']].droplevel(1, axis='columns')
>>> idx_cols
  Specification   Code
0       Model 1  865.0
1             1    NaN
2             2    NaN
```

`.droplevel()` allows to remove that nasty level with `Unnamed:`  values that comes from the merged cells.

Now basically, where `Code` is present, we have the model names, otherwise we have the quantities. So let’s use that to build a 2-level index:

```
>>> quantities = idx_cols['Specification'].where(idx_cols['Code'].isna(), 'Total')
>>> models = idx_cols['Specification'].where(idx_cols['Code'].notna()).ffill()
>>> new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([models, quantities])
>>> new_idx
MultiIndex([('Model 1', 'Total'),
            ('Model 1',       1),
            ('Model 1',       2)],
           names=['Specification', 'Specification'])
```

If we didn’t have `Code` we could have used maybe `idx_cols['Specification'].str.startswith('Model ')`

Now we can assign this index to `df` and see either the « global » columns, or the columns per pen type:

```
>>> df.index = new_idx
>>> all_pen_types = df[['Code', 'Total', 'Black', 'Blue']].droplevel(1, axis='columns')
>>> all_pen_types
                              Code  Total  Black  Blue
Specification Specification                           
Model 1       Total          865.0     20     10    10
              1                NaN     20     10    10
              2                NaN     20     10    10
>>> pen_type = df[['Fountain', 'Pen']]
>>> pen_type
                            Fountain              Pen           
                               Total Black Blue Total Black Blue
Specification Specification                                     
Model 1       Total               20    10   10   NaN   NaN  NaN
              1                   20    10   10   NaN   NaN  NaN
              2                   20    10   10   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

So now your question becomes easy:

- blue fountain pens means column `('Fountain', 'Blue')` in `pen_type`
- Model 1 in set of 2 means `('Model 1', 2)` in the index

```
>>> pen_type.loc[('Model 1', 2), ('Fountain', 'Blue')]
10.0
```